# Java Algorithm: pair list entries by multiple case criteria

Tags: java, algorithm, list

I fear this won't be an easy question. I've been thinking about a proper solution for this problem for a long time and hope that a fresh bunch of brains have a better view on the problem -  let's get to it:

**Data**:

What we're working with here is a csv file containing multiple columns, the relevant ones for this problem are:

- User ID (Integer, ranging from 3 to 8 digits, multiple entries with the same UserID exist) **LIST IS SORTED BY THIS**
- Query (String)
- Epoc (Long, epoc time value)
- clickurl (String)

Every entry in the data we're working with here has !null values for these attributes.

**Example Data:**

```
SID,UID,query,rawdate,timestamp,timegap,epoc,lengthwords,lengthchars,rank,clickurl
5,142,westchester.gov,2006-03-20 03:55:57,Mon Mar 20 03:55:57 CET 2006,0,1142823357504,1,15,1,http://www.westchestergov.com
10,142,207 ad2d 530,2006-04-08 01:31:14,Sat Apr 08 01:31:14 CEST 2006,10000,1144452674507,3,12,1,http://www.courts.state.ny.us
11,142,vera.org,2006-04-08 08:38:42,Sat Apr 08 08:38:42 CEST 2006,11000,1144478322507,1,8,1,http://www.vera.org
```

**Note:** there are multiple entries that have the same value for 'Epoc', this is due to the tools used to gather the data

**Note2:** the list has a size of ~700000, just fyi

**Goal**: Match pairs of entries that have the same query

Scope: entries that share the same UserID

Due to the mentioned anomaly in the data gathering process, the following has to be considered:

If two entries share the same value for 'Query' and for 'Epoc' , the following elements in the list have to be checked for these criteria until the next entry has a different value for one of these attributes. The group of entries that shared the same Query and Epoc values are to be considered as -one- entry, so in order to match a pair, another entry has to be found that matches the 'Query' value. For lack of a better name, let's call a group that shares the same Query and Epoc value a **'chain'**

Now that this is out, it gets a bit easier, there are 3 types of pair compositions we can get out of this:

1. Entry & Entry
2. Entry & Chain
3. Chain & Chain

Type 1 here just means two entries in the list that share the same value for 'Query', but not for 'Epoc'.

So this sums up the **Equal Query Pairs**

There's also the case of **Different Query Pairs** which can be described as the following:

After we have matched the equal query pairs, there's the possibility that there are entries which have not been paired with other entries because their query didn't match - every entry that has not been matched to another entry because of this is part of the **set called 'different queries'**

The members of this set have to be paired without following any criteria, but chains are still treated as -one- entry of the pair.

As for matching the pairs in general, there may be no redundant pairs - a single entry can be part of n many pairs, but two individual entries can only form one pair.

***EXAMPLE:***

The following entries are to be paired

```
UID,Query,Epoc,Clickurl
772,Donuts,1141394053510,https://www.dunkindonuts.com/dunkindonuts/en.html
772,Donuts,1141394053510,https://www.dunkindonuts.com/dunkindonuts/en.html
772,Donuts,1141394053510,https://www.dunkindonuts.com/dunkindonuts/en.html
772,raspberry pi,1141394164710,http://www.raspberrypi.org/
772,stackoverflow,1141394274810,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow
772,stackoverflow,1141394274850,http://www.stackoverflow.com
772,tall women,1141394275921,http://www.tallwomen.org/
772,raspberry pi,1141394277991,http://www.raspberrypi.org/
772,Donuts,114139427999,http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donut
772,stackoverflow,1141394279999,http://www.stackoverflow.com
772,something,1141399299991,http:/something.else/something/
```

In this example, donuts is a chain, therefore the pairs are(linenumbers without header):

- Equal Query Pairs:(1-3,9) (4,8) (5,6) (5,10) (6,10)
- Different Query Pairs: (7,11)

My -failed- approach to the problem:

The algorithm I developed to solve this works as follow:

Iterate the list of entries until the value for UserID changes.

Then, applied to a separate list that only contains the just iterated elements that share the same UserID:

```
   for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            Entry tempI = list.get(i);
            Boolean iMatched = false;
            //boolean to save whether or not c1 is set
            Boolean c1done = false;
            Boolean c2done = false;

        //Hashsets holding the clickurl values of the entries that form a pair
        HashSet<String> c1 = null;
        HashSet<String> c2 = null;

        for (int j = i + 1; j < list.size(); j++) {
            Entry tempJ = list.get(j);
            // Queries match
            if (tempI.getQuery().equals(tempJ.getQuery())) {
                // wheter or not Entry at position i has been matched or not
                if (!iMatched) {
                    iMatched = true;
                }
                HashSet<String> e1 = new HashSet<String>();
                HashSet<String> e2 = new HashSet<String>();
                int k = 0;
                // Times match
                HashSet<String> chainset = new HashSet<String>();
                if (tempI.getEpoc() == tempJ.getEpoc()) {
                    chainset.add(tempI.getClickurl());
                    chainset.add(tempJ.getClickurl());
                } else {
                    e1.add(tempI.getClickurl());
                    if (c1 == null) {
                        c1 = e1;
                        c1done = true;
                    } else {
                        if (c2 == null) {
                            c2 = e1;
                            c2done = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                //check how far the chain goes and get their entries
                if ((j + 1) < list.size()) {
                    Entry tempjj = list.get(j + 1);
                    if (tempjj.getEpoc() == tempJ.getEpoc()) {
                        k = j + 1;
                        //search for the end of the chain
                        while ((k < list.size())
                                && (tempJ.getQuery().equals(list.get(k)
                                        .getQuery()))
                                && (tempJ.getEpoc() == list.get(k).getEpoc())) {

                            chainset.add(tempJ.getClickurl());
                            chainset.add(list.get(k).getClickurl());
                            k++;

                        }
                        j = k + 1; //continue the iteration at the end of the chain
                        if (c1 == null) {
                            c1 = chainset;
                            c1done = true;
                        } else {
                            if (c2 == null) {
                                c2 = chainset;
                                c2done = true;
                            }
                        }

                        // Times don't match
                    }
                } else {
                    e2.add(tempJ.getClickurl());
                    if (c1 == null) {
                        c1 = e2;
                        c1done = true;
                    } else {
                        if (c2 == null) {
                            c2 = e2;
                            c2done = true;
                        }
                    }
                }

                /** Block that compares the clicks in the Hashsets and computes the resulting data
                *  left out for now to not make this any more complicated than it already is
                **/

                // Queries don't match
            } else {
                if (!dq.contains(tempJ)) { //note: dq is an ArrayList holding the entries of the differen query set
                    dq.add(tempJ);
                }
            }

            if (j == al.size() - 1) {
                if (!iMatched) {
                    dq.add(tempI);
                }
            }
        }
        if (dq.size() >= 2) {

            for (int z = 0; z < dq.size() - 1; z++) {
                if (dq.get(z + 1) != null) {
                    /** Filler, iterate dq just like the normal list with two loops
                    *
                    **/
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

So, using an excessive amount of loops I try to match the pairs, resulting in a horribly long runtime which's end I have not seen up until this point

Okay I hope I didn't forget anything crucial, I'll add further needed information later
If you've made it this far, thanks for reading - hopefully you have an idea that might help me

Comment: Could you provide an example with some data, as I'm having trouble understanding this.

Comment: I had a hard time going over this question and understanding the scenario ... can you explain in two sentences what you are trying to achieve? what sort of comparison is needed?

Comment: added examples for both the list data and the pairs. 
@Ronk comparing isn't the problem, pairing is - changed the goal accordingly, might have been misleading

Comment: What is the delimiter for each row?

Comment: a tab, but the data from the csv file is read into an arraylist in java for processing

Answer (score 1):

Use SQL to import the data into a db and then perform the queries. Your txt file is too large; it's no wonder that it takes so long to go through it.  :)

Answer (score 0):

First, remove all but one entry from each chain. To do this, sort by (userid, query, epoch), remove duplicates.

Then, scan the sorted list. take all entries for a (userid, query) pair. If there is only one, save it in a list for later processing, else emit all pairs.

For all the entries for a given user that You have saved for later processing (these are type 2 & 3), emit pairs.